# Is it possible use multiple html pages with phonegap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing android application using phonegap. I am using only one HTML page(index.html).
Is it possible to use multiple HTML pages in application. If YES how it can be done?
Q2: My application Consuming lots of memory space ? How to handle the memory in phonegap applications ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you simply make a link to the other html pages but you might have to re-include phonegap or other javascript libraries.

Memory must be javascript related. What javascript libraries are you using?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Am using the libraries : Jquery Mobile, Iscroll4, Jplot

Comment: Jquery Mobile is a widely used library, so I doubt that'd be the issue of memory. Try taking out Iscroll4 and Jplot 1 by 1 and check memory. It might be one of those.